# Not able to get newest data from kafka broker using kafka-python library

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I'm trying to consume data from Kafka broker using `kafka-python` library and there are multiple brokers which are producing data with high frequency but on Kafka consumer side I need some processing time of around 5 sec , so after processing first message I should get newest message not the next message after last commit offset.

I have tried setting  `enable_auto_commit=False`, and `auto_offset_reset="latest"` I also tried setting random group id , I also tried setting `group_id = None`. only effect of this is I get newest only on start but after that every data comes in sequence of offset not the end of queue or newest data.

```py
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_brokers_address,
                      api_version=(2, 3, 0),
                      group_id='abcd',
                      value_deserializer=lambda v:json.loads(v.decode('utf-8')),
                      enable_auto_commit=False,
                      auto_offset_reset="latest")
    consumer_rpnl.assign([TopicPartition('topic', 0)])

c = next(consumer)
## also tried
for c in consumer:
     print(c.values)
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. Are you able to consume the first message, but not the messages after that?

Answer (score 0):

An example how to move to last from: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1405

```
def seek_to_last():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=config.kafka_bootstrap_server,
                             group_id=config.kafka_check_proxy_thread_group,
                             value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')), auto_offset_reset='latest',
                             enable_auto_commit=True)

    partitions = consumer.partitions_for_topic(config.kafka_raw_proxy_topic)

    if len(partitions) > config.TASK_OK_PROXY_SCAN_THREAD_N:
        logger.error("...................")

    for partation in partitions:
        p = TopicPartition(config.kafka_raw_proxy_topic, partation)
        mypartition = [p]
        consumer.assign(mypartition)
        # consumer.seek_to_end(p)
        last_pos = consumer.end_offsets(mypartition)
        pos = last_pos[p]
        logger.info("%s,  %s" % (partation, pos))
        # consumer.seek(p, pos)
        offset = OffsetAndMetadata(pos, b'')
        consumer.commit(offsets={p: offset})
```